# How to prove a 1-localization of a 1-category is already an $(\infty,1)$-localization?

Tags: reference-request, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories, localization

I don't even know this fits in here or in Mathematics Stack Exchange, but let me ask. I'm new to simplicial stuff, so a good reference would be quite helpful.

Let's say $C$ is a certain category, and that I have combinatorially constructed:

- a relative category $(D(C)\underset{\text{wide}}{\supseteq}  W(C)) \in \mathbf{RelCat}$, and
- a functor $F_C\colon D(C) \to C$ that exhibits $C$ as the weak 1-localization of $(D(C),W(C))$.

By this, I mean that for every 1-category $E$, the precomposition functor
$$
(F_C)^*\colon \operatorname{Fun}(C,E) \to \operatorname{Fun}(D(C), E)
$$
is fully faithful, and its essential image consists of the functors $D(C)\to E$ that map $W(C)$ into the core (i.e., the largest subgroupoid) of $E$.

I have constructed $D(C)$ with meticulous care, and believe that $F_C$ exhibits $C$ as the localization of $(D(C), W(C))$ at the level of $(\infty,1)$-categories. However, I personally find it challenging to demonstrate. Below are some equivalent formulations of "localization at the level of $(\infty,1)$" or "$(\infty,1)$-localization", though I've not verified the proofs of the equivalences:

- Let $N(D(C),W(C)) \in \mathbf{sSet}^+$ denote the marked simplicial set obtained by marking the edges from $W(C)$ in the nerve $N(D(C))$. Let $N(C)^\natural$ stand for the cartesian marked simplicial set with respect to ${!}\colon N(C) \to \Delta[0]$: it is $N(C)$ with its isomorphisms from C marked. Then the induced map $F_C\colon N(D(C), W(C))\to N(C)$ is a weak equivalence in the category of marked simplicial sets $\mathbf{sSet}^+ = \mathbf{sSet}^+/\Delta[0]^\sharp$ with the cartesian model structure.
- The relative functor $F_C\colon (D(C), W(C))\to \min\nolimits^+ C$ is a weak equivalence in the category $\mathbf{RelCat}$ of relative categories endowed with the model structure Quillen equivalent to the model category $\mathbf{ssSet}$ of bisimplicial sets for complete Segal spaces.
  Here, $\min\nolimits^+ C$ denotes the relative category
  $(C\underset{\mathrm{wide}}{\supseteq}\{\mathrm{isomorphisms}\})$.
- Let $L^H(D(C),W(C))\in\mathbf{sCat}=\mathbf{sSet}\mbox{-}\mathbf{Cat}$ denote the hammock localization. Enrich $C$ simplicially with discrete simplicial hom-sets. The simplicial functor $L^H(D(C), W(C)) \to C$ induced by $F_C$ is a Dwyer-Kan equivalence.

I've been trying to prove the third formulation. The induced simplicial functor $F_C\colon L^H(D(C),W(C))\to C$ is strictly surjective on objects, but I found it difficult to prove that the functor has simplicial weak equivalences as hom-maps. I considered of contracting the simplicial set of hammocks into a discrete set of "strings" through a (transfinitely long) zig-zag of simplicial homotopies; however I have not succeeded in moving by homotopy the whole simplicial hom-set consistently with the defining colimits.

I have two things to ask:

1. Am I going on a wrong path? That is, is there an criterion for the desired claim that's easier to prove? (To note: $D(C)$ is seemingly not a model category, and $F_C$ is not a reflective localization) Or is it that I'm doing the right thing and that I just don't have the enough understanding of the concerning simplicial hom-sets?
2. Given a simplicial map from a non-Kan complex to a strictly discrete simplicial set, what would you try in order to prove that the map is a simplicial weak equivalence? A reference (including from textbooks or papers) would be very helpful.

Comment: There is no general methods, so is is very hard to say anything at this level of generality without more information about your precise problem. The most general result there is when W admits a calculus of fraction (right or left) in the sense of Gabriel and Zisman (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/calculus+of+fractions) but that is not the only case where it works.

Comment: お久しぶりです. Does $D(C)$ and/or $C$ have an orthogonal factorization system, just like the category you mention in your other recent question?

Comment: @SergeiBurkin Oh, it's you! Long time no see, お久しぶりです。Yes, the assumptions on $C$ implies that it admits an orthogonal factorization system.

Comment: @gksato Maybe some part of Lemma 4.1 from my first paper on arXiv is relevant? But the situation there is quite special: $D(C)$ has a functor to Segal's category $\Gamma$, and has a factorization system compatible with $(Active, Inert)$ factorization system on $\Gamma$. $L$ in the lemma consists of nice active morphisms, and $R'$ of very nice inert morphisms. On the other hand, the lemma does not use the orthogonal factorization system itself. It uses that any morphism factors nicely as $l\circ r'$, and not the usual $r\circ l$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great reference for these types of questions is Cisinski's book *[Higher categories and homotopical algebra](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/higher-categories-and-homotopical-algebra/C5509D2179302B3F3876A007815A2BBC)*. Definition 2.2.8 on page 35 is for one-categorical localization, and Definition 7.1.2 on page 311 is for $\infty$-categorical localization. Chapter 7 discusses many ways to get at localizations, including via calculus of fractions, hammock localization, and bisimplicial sets (see also chapter 5). Existence of $\infty$-categorical localization (and, yet another way to think about it) is in Proposition 7.1.3. Furthermore, given a functor like your $F_C$, Proposition 7.1.9 gives a characterization for when it's an $\infty$-categorical localization. The subsequent results provide a whole yoga for checking those conditions. Since you write that you're a beginner, I strongly recommend reading this book.

Comment: Thanks for a great reference! I haven't read it through, but it pretty much looks like it contains something I need to learn!